# Get line after match using awk

Tags: awk

I want

```
MAths
asad
2323
dfd
```

to show line after `asad` I do

`awk '{if($1=="asad")next};1' test`

get results

```
MAths
2323
dfd
```

why is `next` not working? I only want to match the `Maths` not the rest of lines. I can do this with `regex` but I want it with comparison `if` condition also I want to save the results in a variable.

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: Your Subject line says you want the line after the match but your question says  "I only want to match the Maths not the rest of lines." Maths is on the line before your match. If you could clarify your question, we would be happy to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
awk 'on{print;on=0} $1=="asad"{on=1}' test
```

The way you have it, the `1` at the end of the script is causing every line to print (except when next is called, which skips it)